# Arduino HC-SR04 sensor, averaged data

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors

I'm trying to control and LED with an average value calculated of distances from an ultrasonic sensor. I have the data being averaged but it is continuous from power up. I want to recalculate the average after every ten readings. Can anyone tell me what I need to change to recalculate the average every 10 values versus calculating a running average?

```
const int TrigPin = 8;
const int EchoPin = 9;
const int LedPin = 13;
const int numReadings = 5;
long Duration = 0;

int readings[numReadings];
int index = 0;
int total = 0;
int average = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TrigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++)
    readings[thisReading] = 0;  
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);

  Duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH);
  long Distance_mm = Distance(Duration);

  //Serial.print("Distance = ");
  //Serial.print(Distance_mm);
  //Serial.println(" mm");

  total= total - readings[index];
  readings[index] = analogRead(EchoPin);
  total = total + readings[index];
  index = index + 1;

  if (index >= numReadings)
    index = 0;

  average = total / numReadings;
  Serial.print("Dist_avg = ");
  Serial.print(average);
  Serial.println("mm");
  delay(100);

  if (average > 400)
  {
    digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  }

}

long Distance(long time)
{
  long DistanceCalc;
  DistanceCalc = ((time /2.9) / 2);
  return DistanceCalc;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change your code so that it calculates the average when index == 10. If you cahnge numReadings to 10, you could try code like this:

```
void loop(){
  ...

 //total= total - readings[index];
 //you don't need the array here anymore
 //readings[index] = analogRead(EchoPin);
 //total = total + readings[index];
 total = total + analogRead(EchoPin);
 index = index + 1;

 if (index >= numReadings)
 {
   index = 0;

   average = total / numReadings;

   Serial.print("Dist_avg = ");
   Serial.print(average);
   Serial.println("mm");
   delay(100);

   if (average > 400)
     digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
   else
     digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW

   total = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to average the last ten readings after every reading, or every 10 readings calculate the average.
In the first case, you need a "rotating array", in the second case you don't need an array, just set total to zero, count the readings, add the reading to the total, then every time the count gets to 10, output the average and set the total to zero again.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this link as a reference, which tells that you should not average sonar data. 
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,20920.0.html